# What is Date Format for "24-OCT-19 09.33.34.000000000 AM"?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to import in SQL Developer but i am getting dates in following format:

```
24-OCT-19 09.33.34.000000000 AM
```

SQL Developer is not ready to accept that and giving following issue:
[image]

Tried following without success:

```
dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.milliseconds am/pm
DD-MMM-yy hh12.mm.ss.fff tt
```

Comment: try this one `TO_timestamp('24-OCT-19 09.33.34.000000000 AM','DD-MON-YY hh.mi.ss.ff AM' , 'nls_date_language=american')`

Comment: That's a timestamp, not a date

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for Oracle format models is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-49B32A81-0904-433E-B7FE-51606672183A).

- `MMM` is not a valid format model, you want `MON` for a 3-character month name.
- `mm` is not minutes, its 2-digit month
- You're missing the fractional seconds and the `AM/PM` part.

For a string

```
24-OCT-19 09.33.34.000000000 AM
```

You can use the format model:

```
DD-MON-RR HH12.MI.SS.FF9 AM
```

*(Note: You probably want the `RR` year format so that `99` is `1999`. If you use the `YY` year format then `99` would be of the current century, so `2099`.)*

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that which is the data type of the column so you can use the following format accordingly:

```
-- timestamp
    TO_TIMESTAMP('24-OCT-19 09.33.34.000000000 AM', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM')

-- date
    TO_DATE('24-OCT-19 09.33.34 AM', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS AM')
```

Cheers!!